# Google Apps Script: Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com returned code 403

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to make a simple script to lock a document (aka: making it read-only). However, I keep running into this error:

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
docuLock    @ Code.gs:7
```

I somehow got it to work on one document, but when I make a copy of that document, i'd the script returns that error on the new document every time. Does anybody have any idea what I can do to fix this? The idea is to have one document that serves as a template, and I can make a copy of it (with the script attached) and make edits to the new one however I want, and still be able to use the locking script.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```js
function docuLock() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId());

  const docID = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  Logger.log("Doc ID: " + docID);

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${docID}`, {
    method: 'PATCH',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`,
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      contentRestrictions: [
        {
          readOnly: true,
          reason: 'Prevent accidental editing',
        },
      ],
    }),
  });

  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().saveAndClose();
  DocumentApp.openByUrl(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getUrl())

}

function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('DocuLock')
      .addItem('Lock Document', 'docuLock')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The reason you are receiving is this error is because you are not using any / not using the appropriate scopes for making the request.**

Since you are making the request using `UrlFetchApp` and not making use of `DriveApp` or the advanced Drive service, the scopes are **not** added automatically and you have to manually add the ones you need.

In order to fix this, you will have to modify your manifest `appsscript.json` file and add the Drive scope/s using the `oauthScopes` key:

- `appsscript.json`

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
  ]
}
```

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 - Authenticate your users](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth);
- [Drive API v3 - Handling errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors);
- [Apps Script Manifests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests).